# provision Homestead to automatically migrate tables

Tags: migration, provisioning, homestead

Is there a way to use after.sh to run `php artisan migrate`?

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd exercise-8
vagrant ssh
php artisan migrate
```

I realized a few things

- you have to `vagrant ssh` before you do migrations
- the bash script runs from `/home/vagrant`
- `vagrant ssh` returns `/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: vagrant: command not found`
- `php artisan` returns

  ==> default:
  ==> default:   [PDOException]
  ==> default:   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user     'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  ==> default:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd *
php artisan migrate
```

Explanation:
`cd *` enter the only folder you'll have on `/home/vagrant`
Since these commands are executed on Homestead you do not need `vagrant ssh`.